# Search by word, category, tag, author

Tags: categories, search, tags, author

I want to make a search page, offering search functionalities by:
1) word
2) tag
3) category
4) author
Can you recommend any technique, any guideline as per how to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to add some radio buttons inside your search form. Then add a filter to your search:

```
function filter_search( $query ) {
if( $query->is_search ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['tag']) )
            // alter your search query here.
}
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'filter_search' );
```

Influenced by http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-search-filter-by-custom-values#post-1463329

Comment: I ll have that in mind in case I build the query string manually via radio-boxes and text-boxes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer to let a WordPress plugin handle the work for you, check out [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/), in the WordPress plugin repository.

Increases WordPress' default search functionality in three easy steps using Search Everything.

**Better WordPress search in three steps**

Activate Configure options Search ( maybe that's only two steps )

Options include search highlight, searching pages, excerpts, attachments, drafts, comments and custom fields (metadata).

**What it does:**

Search Everything increases the ability of the default WordPress Search, options included:

- Search Highlighting
- Search Every Page
- Search Every Tag
- Search Custom Taxonomies ( new )
- Search Every Category
- Search non-password protected pages only
- Search Every Comment
- Search only approved comments
- Search Every Draft
- Search Every Excerpt
- Search Every Attachment (post type)
- Search Every Custom Field (metadata)
- Exclude Posts from search
- Exclude Categories from search

### [[WordPress Plugin]: Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/)

Comment: great idea, I ve tried it for custom post types search and it works, thanks!

Comment: This plugin is helpful but it does the opposite from what I need: it takes as input a word and searches tags, categories, titles etc for this word. What I need is criteria like: categoryZ & tag "XYY" & title contains "House". So I guess this plugin is not usable here. Correct?